# How VFS knows which underlying File system functions to be called?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, vfs

When ever we fire a command on linux terminal.The process thus created traverses to the VFS layer,where it decides which file system function to be called like ext4 ,ext3 or anyother filesystem. So my question is How does the VFS differntiate the filesystems? form where the VFS gets the filesystem information,is it the fs_struct in task_struct that tells the VFS ?

Comment: Before a filesystem can be accessed, it has to be mounted. This mount operation is the source of the filesystem information.

Answer (score 3):

As a part of the FS implementation you need to implement file, inode, superblock operations, which will register the the underlying FS ops (ex: ext3_open()) with VFS layer. Depending the the path to the file provided to the open(), VFS will invoke the appropriate file system specific implementation of the syscall.

Lets say you have already mounted a file system, when you are mounting a file system you register your FS for specific operations with VFS layer during the module initialization. During this step, two handlers get_sb() and kill_sb(). get_sb() is called at the time of mounting the file system. kill_sb() is called at the time of unmounting the file system.

For more information refer to [RKFS](http://www2.comp.ufscar.br/~helio/fs/rkfs.html) and look into the how the file operations are implemented along with the data flow diagrams.